# Can't clone my old Windows 10 system to RAID 0 in new build

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, raid, clone

Going crazy trying to get my new build to boot. I need to restore my old system from an external usb drive to a RAID 0 created in the new motherboard bios. I’ve updated the raid drivers in Windows device manager and the drive shows as a single drive in disk manager. I’ve cloned my OS from the usb drive to the ssd raid using Acronis True Image 2019 several times and also with other software. It will not boot from the cloned OS raid drive. I’ve used install media from ATI 2019, Macrium and Aomei, each with the RAID and controller drivers included. The OS raid shows no MBR, page file or crash dump. When I do a system transfer by booting into EaseUS ToDo with a USB thumbdrive and use a system image of my OS from the usb created earlier I get exactly the same result. I’m wondering if this could possibly be a faulty setting on my part in the bios. I can’t run in UEFI because if I do, I get an error message that says “there is no GOP support detected in this card (which is related to the graphics card I have installed). Bios setting will be changed to CSM.” I’ve tried to use Win install media to repair, used the command prompt to try boot fixes of various kinds. Getting nowhere. I have done this type of build several times before and always cloned my current system to a single drive and then once up and running, cloned it to the RAID 0. Never had a problem like this. I have my old system complete and working, seems like there must be a way to get it running on the RAID as I’ve done in the past. Any help will be **greatly** appreciated. Thanks for taking a look.

B450 Tomahawk Max II (flashed/updated to newest bios)

Ryzen 3600

EVGA GTX 570 graphics card (no UEFI bios available)

32gb ram

7C02v39 processor bios (most current)

Comment: What are the disks sizes? Old disk vs new RAID 0 size.

Comment: My recollection of Acronis is that a clone made from the active boot drive may not work. You need to boot from a different drive to run Acronis.

Comment: Hi, this is my first post so I hope I'm answering in the proper fashion by posting a comment to answer the questions above. "What are the disks sizes? Old disk vs new RAID 0 size." The old disk is a Seagate 2TB USB drive. The new drive, which is exactly the same set as the system was on before the new MB, processor, etc. is a RAID 0 with 2 PNY 480GB SSD's. Thanks eventHandler

Comment: Hi Charles Kenyon.  "You need to boot from a different drive to run Acronis." I'm assuming that you mean I should take the USB system drive and clone it to another from a computer other than my new build. That's sounds good to me. I'll do that from my laptop and see how it goes. Thanks.